# Most efficient way to forward example.com to example.com/subfolder?

Tags: htaccess, dns, subdomain, 301-redirect

Title says my entire question. I think I saw someone forward `example.com` to `example.com/subfolder` and have spent about a week trying to figure out how to best do this.

My goal is to have user type in `example.com?id=cow` and go to `example.com/subfolder/index.php?id=cow`, yet still see `example.com?id=cow` in the address bar.

I've messed with masking, DNS, looked a little into htcaccess (I've done very very little in htcaccess) I'm really at a loss as to what to type into Google to find what i'm trying to do, any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Quick and dirty: option one is to use iFrames on the `http://domain.com/?id=cow` to show the content of `http://example.com/subfolder/index.php?id=cow` and option two is (since it's PHP) to actually get the contents of the (remote?) website and render it where you want it (use cURL or file_get_contents or something).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do this with mod_rewrite on domain.com.  A simple RewriteRule to redirect your example would be:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subfolder/index.php [L,QSA]`

The ^(*.)$ captures any request on domain.com.

`http://example.com/subfolder/index.php` is where you want people to end up

The `L` tells mod_rewrite to stop matching and go.  `QSA` stands for Query String Appended and should preserve the query string.